# runSD with NULL values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as given below:

```
 > dput(head(dt[,c("IBC","FYEAR","GVKEY")],20))
 structure(list(IBC = c(1.138, 2.576, NA, 0.236, 0.793, -0.525, -7.838, -2.554, 9.071, 11.506, 15.361, 21.233, 24.814, 25.655, NA, 10.02, 0.283, 9.484, 10.463, 16.012), 
                FYEAR = c(1984L, 1985L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L), GVKEY = c(1001L, 1001L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L)),
                .Names = c("IBC", "FYEAR", "GVKEY"),
                row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The following code generates standard deviation for the column called `IBC` for each consecutive sequence of 4 elements. However, I get an error when there is a `NULL` value. How can I modify the following code to make room for `NULL` values?

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$GVKEY,dt$FYEAR),]
dt$STDEARN <- ave(dt$IBC, dt$GVKEY, FUN = function(x) {
                  if(length(x)>3) c(NA,head(runSD(x,4),-1))
                  else sample(NA,length(x),TRUE)
               })
```

Comment: An atomic vector cannot include `NULL` values. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: provided reproducible example.

Comment: What is your expected output of `runSD` if the data contains `NA`?

Comment: should be similar to sd(x, na.rm = TRUE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `rollapply` instead of `runSD` since you can use `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$GVKEY,dt$FYEAR),]

library(xts)
transform(dt, STDEARN = ave(IBC, GVKEY, FUN = function(x) 
                             if (length(x) > 3)
                               c(rep(NA, 3), head(rollapply(x, 4, sd, 
                                                            na.rm = TRUE, 
                                                            fill = NA), -3))
                             else NA))

      IBC FYEAR GVKEY   STDEARN
1   1.138  1984  1001        NA
2   2.576  1985  1001        NA
3      NA  1984  1003        NA
4   0.236  1985  1003        NA
5   0.793  1986  1003        NA
6  -0.525  1987  1003        NA
7  -7.838  1988  1003  0.661626
8  -2.554  1989  1003  4.039287
9   9.071  1984  1004        NA
10 11.506  1985  1004        NA
11 15.361  1986  1004        NA
12 21.233  1987  1004        NA
13 24.814  1988  1004  5.302228
14 25.655  1989  1004  5.938866
15     NA  1990  1004  4.680553
16 10.020  1991  1004  2.348224
17  0.283  1992  1004  8.794155
18  9.484  1993  1004 12.799745
19 10.463  1994  1004  5.473495
20 16.012  1995  1004  4.869479
```